# A finite connected set with more than one element

Tags: real-analysis

Does such a set exist? I've tried some examples and it seems to me that there always exists disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that the original set is in their union. So would this mean any finite set is connected iff it has only 1 element?

Comment: What are your spaces? Metric spaces?

Comment: @Mike Miller in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Hint: Points are closed in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

If your space is $\mathbb { R }$ this is impossible(your tag is "real analysis"). In the real line the  connected sets are only intervals. 
Proof: 
If $I $ is a connected set of real line, we take 2 elements $x, y\in I$, $(x <y) $. If $I$ is connected , for all $ z$ such that $x <z <y$ , $z\in I$. If  $z\not\in I$, then $I=I\cap (-\infty, z)\cup I\cap (z,\infty)\ $, this is absurd!

Comment: Is there a way to prove this rigorously? That a finite set is connected only if it contains only one element

Comment: See my last answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, consider any finite set with the indiscrete topology. In other words, $X$ finite with the topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, there are spaces for which this is possible, but it cannot happen in $\mathbb R$.

Here's the proof:

Suppose $X \subset \mathbb R$ is a finite set with more than one element. Let $a, b \in X$. Since $X$ is finite, there exists $c \notin X$ such that $a < c < b$. Then $(X \cap (-\infty, c)) \cup (X \cap (c, \infty))$ is a separation of $X$.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you